# Magento 2.4.5 - p1 Getting error while executing MFTF testing with codecept using PHPStorm on XAMPP local

Tags: magento2.4.5p1, mftf

If anyone have idea then please share with me about codecept to execute MFTF

I am getting below error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Module\LC_MESSAGES" in C:\xampp\htdocs\integration2\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Lib\Di.php:85

So how to resolve this error, please help me. Thanks.